# Return only the first instance of a variable based on another

Tags: r

I have a list of ID's (some are duplicates) and I have a `KEEP` variable.  I'd like to create a column that is either 1 or 0 if there is an instance of this in the KEEP column, even if it's not that particular column

```
id <- c(101,101,101,102,102,102,103,103,103,104,104,106,107,108)
keep <- c("Y",0,0,"Y",0 ,0 ,"Y" ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0)
df <- data.frame(id, keep)
```

I want to create a third column that has a 1 if there is a Y in the keep column for all ID's that match.

It should look something like this.

```
> df

    id keep countkeep
1  101    Y         1
2  101    0         1
3  101    0         1
4  102    Y         1
5  102    0         1
6  102    0         1
7  103    Y         1
8  103    0         1
9  103    0         1
10 104    0         0
11 104    0         0
12 106    0         0
13 107    0         0
14 108    0         0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id)%>% mutate(countkeep = ifelse(any(keep=="Y"),1,0))

      id   keep countkeep
   <dbl> <fctr>     <dbl>
1    101      Y         1
2    101      0         1
3    101      0         1
4    102      Y         1
5    102      0         1
6    102      0         1
7    103      Y         1
8    103      0         1
9    103      0         1
10   104      0         0
11   104      0         0
12   106      0         0
13   107      0         0
14   108      0         0
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, and it was done very efficiently in dplyr, which I like too.  Awesome job.  Thank

Comment: When the user downvotes, please also share the reason.It would really help

Answer (score 4):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, countkeep := +(any(keep=="Y")), id]
df
#     id keep countkeep
# 1: 101    Y         1
# 2: 101    0         1
# 3: 101    0         1
# 4: 102    Y         1
# 5: 102    0         1
# 6: 102    0         1
# 7: 103    Y         1
# 8: 103    0         1
# 9: 103    0         1
#10: 104    0         0
#11: 104    0         0
#12: 106    0         0
#13: 107    0         0
#14: 108    0         0
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$countkeep <- with(df, as.integer(ave(keep=="Y", id, FUN = any)))
```

Or with `table`

```
transform(df, countkeep = +(id %in% names(na.omit(NA^!table(df)[,"Y"]))))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you would like a base answer, this one should work, too.

```
df$countkeep <- ifelse(df$id %in% df$id[which(df$keep == "Y")], 1, 0)

> df
    id keep countkeep
1  101    Y         1
2  101    0         1
3  101    0         1
4  102    Y         1
5  102    0         1
6  102    0         1
7  103    Y         1
8  103    0         1
9  103    0         1
10 104    0         0
11 104    0         0
12 106    0         0
13 107    0         0
14 108    0         0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant way to do this, but this works:

```
df$countkeep <- apply(df,1,function(x){
  if(nrow(subset(df,id==x[1] & keep=="Y"))==1)
    1
  else
    0
})
```

**How it works:**

**Overview:** We look through the rows of df. If there is a row that has this row's id, and "Y" as keep, mark this row's `countkeep` as 1. If there is no instance of `id` and "Y", mark 0.

- [`apply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) with `1` as the 2nd param loops through the rows of a
  data frame, applying the function to each row.
- [`subset`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/subset.html) Picks the rows that meet a condition. In this case,
  we're looking for rows that have the same id as the current row, and
  a keep value of "Y".
- [`&`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html) Combines conditions
- [`nrow`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/nrow.html) gets the number of rows